# How to eliminate gaps in a sequence of numbers?

Tags: r, dplyr, rank, dense-rank

I am an R newbie and am trying to figure out how to remove gaps > 1 in sequences of numbers, but not make changes to sequences if there are no gaps. So for example using `dplyr::dense_rank` I get these desired results:

```
> dplyr::dense_rank(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 5))
[1] 1 1 2 2 3
```

But executing the following gives me these undesired results:

```
> dplyr::dense_rank(c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2))
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
```

When I would these results to be:

```
[1] 2 2 2 2 2
```

And as another example a sequence of 2,2,5,8 would be condensed to 2,2,3,4; or 5,5,5,10 condenses to 5,5,5,6 etc.

Is there an easy way to do this? With a preference for `dplyr` if possible!

Comment: The dplyr::dense_rank command does what it does and which makes sense. It creates a ranking for your list, starting with rank 1 and if there is a second value which is equal to the lowest value, then it is also rank 1. Your example: 5,5,5,10 should lead to 1,1,1,2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for

```
## `x` is a vector of integers (can contain negative values)
dplyr::dense_rank(x) + min(x) - 1
```

or even

```
## if `x` is non-decreasing
dplyr::dense_rank(x) + x[1] - 1
```